# Determining whether ODE solutions are square-integrable by approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I saw it claimed that whether or not the solutions to an ODE are $L^2$ could be determined by solving an easier ODE with asymptotically similar coefficients and I'm stuck on determining how. The specific example was that if we want to know about square-integrability near $0$ of solutions to
$$-u'' + 2x^{-2} (1+x)^{-2}u = 0$$
(on say $x \in (0, \infty)$), then we can instead solve
$$-u'' + 2x^{-2}u=0$$
I've solved this easier equation, but I'm stuck trying to prove how that tells us about the solutions to the original.

Comment: If you just want to know about the square-integrability near $0$, then use the Frobenius method to determine the behavior of the solution near the regular-singular point $x=0$. You do not need to apply the whole method, just find the indices. You will find that one solution is s.-i. through $x=0$. Also, it is easy to see that the simpler equation will have the same behavior so it works as well. However, if, ultimately, you want to prove it is $L^2(0,\infty)$, seems to me you need to worry about $x=\infty$ as well. One finds, at $x=\infty$, that one solution is s.-i.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation has the form
$$
u''+p(x)u'+q(x)u=0,
$$
where $p=0$ and $q$ is singular at $x=0$. However,
$$
x^2q(x)=-\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}
$$
is analytic at $x=0$ with
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} x^2q(x)=-2.
$$
Thus, $x=0$ is a regular singular point. By the theorem on the Frobenius method, there is a series expansion about $x=0$ of the form
$$
u=x^r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n.
$$
To find $r$, we compute the indicial equation
$$
r(r-1)+0r-2=0\to r^2-r-2=0\to r=-1,2.
$$
Thus, one solution, the one corresponding to $r=2$, is square integrable at $x=0$ since, for that solution,
$$
u=\mathcal{O}(x^2)\text{ as }x\to 0.
$$
Note that the solution corresponding to $r=-1$ is not square integrable since it behaves as $1/x$ as $x\to 0$.

Your simplified equation is an Euler equation with the same indicial equation, which is all that matters when determining the behavior of the solution near $x=0$. So, that simplified equation has the solutions $u=x^2$, square integrable, and $u=1/x$, not square integrable.